# Auth log error : Is it a Hack?

Tags: hacking, bugzilla

I was just going through auth.log file, I found the following error. Can anybody tell is it a hack or just log of Bugzilla which I installed & throughing  an error.

```
Mar 12 06:50:10 bigbugz02 su[13762]: Successful su for www-data by root
Mar 12 06:50:10 bigbugz02 su[13762]: + ??? root:www-data
Mar 12 06:50:10 bigbugz02 su[13762]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user www-data by (uid=0)
Mar 12 06:50:12 bigbugz02 su[13762]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user www-data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a frequently asked question in [Secure Debian](http://www.linuxsecurity.com/docs/harden-doc/html/securing-debian-howto/) guide. Here is some more info on the topic:

[See point 11.2.3 here](http://www.linuxsecurity.com/docs/harden-doc/html/securing-debian-howto/ch11.en.html)

Generally it could be a cron job. So - it is safe.

Comment: Yeah...the logs can be frightening :)

Answer (score 0):

This is generally a safe thing. When the application is started by root user it does this to start it as www-data user.

Answer (score 0):

It means a cron job has executed. Depends on if you have set up cron jobs, this could mean a hack.

I found that I'm hacked:

```
# crontab -l -u www-data
*/10 * * * * /var/tmp/iFuEAeuC >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I uploaded the file to virustotal, and it says it's some type of virus...